# Prestashop 1.6: Cart.php quantity of whole cart

Tags: cart, prestashop-1.6

How i can get quantity of whole cart in file `cart.php`, i search somethings like `in tpl {$cart_qties}`

thx for answer

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about Classes/Cart.php there is:

`/** * Return cart products quantity
  * * @result integer Products quantity */ 
public function nbProducts() { if (!$this->id) { return 0; } return Cart::getNbProducts($this->id); }`

pls edit it is hard paste code on phone ;-)